# How to create a timeline with evenly spaced intervals on excel or powerpoint as seen in this image?

Tags: excel, powerpoint, timeline

I'm trying to duplicate this timeline graph seen in the picture. I understand I can make the shapes, fill in the color, and add text; however, I'm having a hard time creating the simple timeline on excel and powerpoint. In other words how do I create the evenly spaced 1 hour timeline seen in this image?

[image: Example of timeline I'm trying to replicate]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a chart with all elements deleted except for the bottom axis.

You could also create a 3-row table, with the horizontal line being the border between rows 1 and 2. The numbers can be placed in row 3.